# Disable system shortcut for a single application

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, emacs

When I use emacs, I want to be able to use C-q (quoted-insert).
However when I do that in Unity, the program quits since C-q is the system-wide shortcut I set for closing a window.

I want to keep C-q active for all programs but emacs, for which I want it disabled.

I recall from the time I had Windows at work that autohotkey allowed to redefine (and disable) shortcuts for applications separately, and to override the possible system behavior of such shortcuts. It is something similar I want here.

Note: Autokey does not seem to preempt Ctrl+q from the sytem (beside not pasting text at all, at least in my 14.04).

Comment: Was not able to recreate in 14.04, both windowed emacs and in-terminal. I think ctrl+q is not system wide...

Comment: Sorry, I might have defined the system wide ctrl+q myself (I need to remove my eyes from the screen to find Alt+F4, that is why I dislike it). I want to keep ctrl+q, but disable it for a single application (emacs).